# Calculating MySQL Select field based on previously calculated field

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

So I have a phone customer database in MySQL, the database has two tables, `customer_master` and `call_data`. Both the tables have a `customer_id` field that matches individual customer numbers with certain attributes. The `customer_master` table has the customer names, and the `call_data` has tons of call data associated with a unique customer ID. I need to create a query where I get the number of local calls attempted, and then the number off successful local calls placed (not dropped calls) based on the call events and calculate an average. The `call_data` table has a `call_event` field where I essentially need to look for two different things a) `local_call_failure` and `local_call_success`. I'm able to create a query where I can use an `inner join` to display my table with the `userID`, `user name`, and `total local attempts`, however I can't figure out how to then use that calculated attempt value to then calculate the local call success average. Here is how I get the total attempts by picking out the local calls based on `call_event`:

```
SELECT customer_id,
CONCAT(name_first, ' ', name_last) AS 'Customer Name',
COUNT(CM.call_event) AS 'Total Local Attemps'
FROM customer_master CM
INNER JOIN call_data CD ON CM.customer_id = CD.customer_id
AND ((call_event = 'local_call_failure')
     OR (call_event = 'local_call_success') )
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Now I can create another query to calculate the total successful local calls placed by using the same idea above, except in the `AND` statement, only include `call_event = 'local_call_success'`. If I could somehow figure out how to do these independently and then calculate the average by just dividing `call_success/tota_call_attempts`, that's all I need! In any other language this would take me one loop and five minutes, but SQL seems to be much more difficult. I need to get both calculations completed in the same query, and print them out side by side, then make another column for the average. How can this be accomplished? From what I've been able to gather, setting a variable like `@var_name := COUNT(CM.call_event)` and then using that variable to perform a calculation again inside your `SELECT` statement is a no-no in SQL.

Can anyone help me with this? I'd be forever in your debt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
select cm.customer_id,
       concat(cm.name_first, ' ', cm.name_last) AS `Customer Name`, 
       count(*) as total_attempts,
       sum( cd.call_event = 'local_call_failure' ) as num_failures,
       sum( cd.call_event = 'local_call_failure' ) / count(*) as failure_rate
from customer_master cm join
     call_data cd 
     on cm.customer_id = cd.customer_id and
        cd.call_event in ('local_call_failure', 'local_call_success')
group by customer_id, `Customer Name`;
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! This works perfectly for me! I knew I was close and that it should be a relatively easy solution. I tried everything but putting all the conditions for the query in the actual aggregate function

Comment: Also I should mention for anyone else who comes along with the same issue. I had to use the aggregate function you suggested `sum` as opposed to the function `count` which I had been using. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

using sql server syntax, which I am sure will be very close to the same:

```
select customer_id, CONCAT(name_first, ' ', name_last) AS 'Customer Name', 
COUNT(CM.call_event) AS 'Total Local Attemps',
sum(case when call_event = 'local_call_success' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Success Events',
sum(case when call_event = 'local_call_success' then 1 else 0 end)/COUNT(CM.call_event) as SuccesstRate
from customer_master CM
INNER JOIN call_data CD ON CM.customer_id = CD.customer_id
AND ((call_event = 'local_call_failure')
    OR (call_event = 'local_call_success')
    )
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I appreciate all the help. I ended up needing to use Gordon's answer below, because the aggregate function `SUM` ended up being needed over `COUNT`, but that was my mistake, not yours. Thanks again!